# No longer able to install apps or updates

Tags: software-installation, updates, software-sources

After trying to install WINE from the WINE HQ .deb, I can no longer get updates or install apps without getting the message:

E: Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

This is Kubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

I don't know what the 55 refers to, as there are fewer than 55 sources in the list. I've noticed the file sources.list.save is slightly longer than the file sources.list, but don't know whether switching these files will damage anything. I don't see where I can attach the working file (assumption on my part) in case it's needed for review. Please let me know what other information I can provide to help solve this problem.

Thanks, I didn't see where I could edit the question. Here goes...

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb https://dl/winehq.org/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl/winehq.org/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Comment: Paste the contents of the `sources.list` to your question if you have no clue where is the line 55.

Comment: Thank You for responding. Here is the contents of the file.  # deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

Comment: Where is "here"? [edit] the question and paste it there.

Comment: Having to post in several parts due to text capacity limits.    ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe

Comment: You can't post it to comments. [edit] the question.

Comment: NO. PLEASE DON'T POST IT TO COMMENTS.

Comment: # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

Comment: I pasted the file to the ticket, but it appears it didn't stick.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines

```
deb https://dl/winehq.org/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl/winehq.org/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

and all should be done.

Comment: I see other references to winehq.org. Is it just this one line causing the problem?

Comment: The line 55 is causing the problem. Others are commented out but are crap too.

Comment: Looks like your answer was spot-on. Thank You so much. I'll have to forget about WINE, as I followed their instructions, which caused this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You made typos with the commands. Don't type them, but copy and paste ;-)

Comment: Good tip, Thanks again.